# How to change width of object in mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have a div class called `form-groupBlogg`

It is a form in which I want to adjust the width of it in both ordinary computer and mobile version. I have written the following CSS:

```
.form-groupBlogg{
  width:74%;
  margin-top:20px;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
  .form-groupBlogg {
   width: 80%;
  }
}
```

Only problem is that the `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)`-part wont adjust the width of the div class in the mobile version. The first part with the `width: 74%` works correctly. How can I adjust the width in the mobile version?

Comment: Could you please share which mobile device you are testing on and what browser you are using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and Samsung S5 device.

Comment: Are you pushing updates to your site now? Seems like the styling has changed a couple times while visiting your site. In that case, are you testing the answers on the live site? You should definitely have a development environment where you do these tests. Also: it makes it harder for us to help and test on your site if you continuously change it.

Comment: Sorry for this, you are right. How can I do this in an development environment?

Comment: For a basic environment (for wordpress) I recommend setting up WAMP (windows), MAMP (osx) or LAMP (linux) depending on your OS. Install wordpress and get a copy of your site. This way you can work locally, see if stuff works and then push to your live site. You can probably just google some guides on how to set it up. On windows/osx it is basically just a one-click install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEW answer:
I guess you just want a wider form on the small screens.

Your site is adjusted in a wrapper, so the width:80% is small on a small screen. Try to adjust the width of the form-groulBlogg and form-group to 100% on the smallest screens. Looks better in my tests.

Try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)  {
    .form-groupBlogg {width: 100%;}
    .form-group {width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: I tried that too unfortunately but it did not work. [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/blogga-om-oss/)

Comment: Hm, I tried it but it changes the whole layout since I have a `padding-left:18px` also. The above code you gave me somehow also changes the stationary layout.

Comment: There is a typo in there... Let me fix that

Comment: Try now. I had put a colon after .form-group:  That breaks the css... :-(